# ACF add custom fields to categories and display

Tags: categories, advanced-custom-fields

Trying to display custom fields for categories on a category page.

1. I added the fields to ACF in the category taxonomy
2. Added this snippet into my custom category category-emails.php

   ```
   $image = get_field('header_image', 'category_74'); 
   echo($image);
   ```

This works. It renders out the data I have in 'header_image'.

The problem is, `category_74` is hardcoded into the template. So it will only show that header_image for category_74. Trying to make it so any category or sub category of category 74 has field 'header_image' available and that I wont have to modify the template.

Is there a way to write something more general, that replaces 'category_74' with something like 'categories'... I tried categories but didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this page out from the ACF docs: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-a-taxonomy-term/

Specifically this section:

"Finding the term related to the current post"

```
<?php

// load all 'category' terms for the post
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category');


// we will use the first term to load ACF data from
if( !empty($terms) ) {

    $term = array_pop($terms);

    $custom_field = get_field('header_image', $term );

    // do something with $custom_field
}

?>
```

I changed their "category_image" to your "header_image" value. I *think* that should work for you.

Comment: you are a genius. "Genius. Genius. Genius" that totally worked!